# Adding a css class to Angular Directive Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `<my-directive>` that is an element. I do not use link or compile, just:

```
export default function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
        controller: mydirective,
        controllerAs: 'mine',
        bindToController: {}
    }
}
```

This of course is a fake directive, but the issue I have is being able to add a css class on this directive when it is in the DOM.

if there is anymore information I need to add, please let me know.

Comment: Why won't `<my-directive class="someClass"></my-directive>` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could target the directive's tag from your CSS/scss stylesheet, this way:

Say you have:

```
<mydirect></mydirect>
```

So in styles.css:

```
mydirect {
  background-color: red;
}
```